# Efficient way to find index of interval

Tags: python

I'm writing a spline class in Python. The method to calculate the the spline interpolated value requires the index of the closest x data points. Currently a simplified version looks like this:

```
def evaluate(x):
    for ii in range(N): # N = len(x_data)
        if x_data[ii] <= x <= x_data[ii+1]:
            return calc(x,ii)
```

So it iterates through the list of `x_data` points until it finds the lower index `ii` of interval in which `x` lies and uses that in the function `calc`, which performs the spline interpolation. While functional, it seems like this would be inefficient for large `x_data` arrays if `x` is close to the end of the data set. Is there a more efficient or elegant way to perform the same functionality, which does not require every interval to be checked iteratively?

Note: `x_data` may be assumed to be sorted so `x_data[ii] < x_data[ii+1]`, but is not necessarily equally spaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is exactly what bisect is for https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

```
from bisect import bisect
index = bisect(x_data,x)
#I dont think you actually need the value of the 2 closest but if you do here it is
point_less = x_data[index-1]  # note this will break if its index 0 so you probably want a special case for that
point_more = x_data[index]

closest_value = min([point_less,point_more],key=lambda y:abs(x-y))
```

alternatively you should use binary search(in fact im pretty sure thats what bisect uses under the hood) .... it should be  worst case `O(log n)` (assuming your input array is already sorted)

Comment: That's order O(log n), actually. And I just looked at the source code for `bisect()`: it is a binary search.

Comment: I don't think this quite works. `bisect([0,1,2], 0.1])` gives 1, not 0, so comparing the values at `index` and `index+1` will be looking at `[1,2]`, not `[0,1]`.

Comment: @DSM that is because bisect search for a insertion point for x such that x_data remain in sorted order, just subtract 1 to the result and correct for negatives and that should do the trick